# Realtime count lines in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Jsfiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/dandrade78/vejf34bc/2/)
The code work in Jsfiddle

Dont work in firefox or any browser
Line error:tarea.addEventListener('input', update)
Error is Firefox "TypeError: tarea is null" 
Error in Chrome is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Please help me. I am looking for an effective solution, with simple code that works correctly

```
  <html>
    <head>
         <title>Counter</title>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   // Encapsulate function to document.ready now not error.     
    $(document).ready(function(){
   var tarea = document.querySelector('#ta')
   var input = document.querySelector('#rt')

    function update() {
   var res = (tarea.value.match(/\n/g)) ? tarea.value.match(/\n/g).length : 0;

     input.value = res;
   }
   tarea.addEventListener('input', update) //Error Here
   });

tarea.addEventListener('input', update) //Error Here

$(document).ready(function(){
         if (jQuery) {  
           // jQuery is loaded  
            alert("Jquery load!");
         } else {
           // jQuery is not loaded
           alert("Jquery Doesn't Work");
         }
      });

</script>
<body>
   <textarea name="ta" id="ta" rows="4" cols="50">
      ABC
      DEF
      GHI
  </textarea>
    <input type="text" id="rt" name="textnumber" value="">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, make correction sample code Jsfiddle, I am novice

Answer (score 1):

Put your code through a validator. I think you have missing semi-colons and bad braces.

I see you're using jQuery. Something like this should suffice:

```js
$(function() {
  var tarea = $('#ta');
  var input = $('#rt');
  function update(e) {
    var val = tarea.val(),
    matches = val.match(/\n/g),
    res = (matches) ? val.match(/\n/g).length : 0;
    if(val.length){res++;}
    input.val(res);
  }
  tarea.on("input", update)
  .trigger("input");//set initial value
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="ta" id="ta" rows="4" cols="50">ABC
DEF
GHI</textarea>
<input type="text" id="rt" name="textnumber" value="">
```

Comment: in your script it show start from 0. how to make it start from 1?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you're trying to access the element before the document is fully loaded.

You should either move your JavaScript code at the end (right before the closing `</body>` tag) or move all your event handling code (including the tarea definition) to `$(document).ready(...)`.

Comment: You need to move all the relevant code there, **including the `tarea` definition**.

Comment: The document.ready() is I think the best practice especially as the OP already has one...